# False Positives- Server side protection against XSS

Tags: web-application, web-browser, php, xss

I read about XSS attacks and its prevention mechanism on server-side. It seems only protection is to sanitize the input by escaping special characters on server side (Using some PHP functions such as `htmlspecialchars()` ). I have read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss). So now suppose some input like `3<2hello 4>3` or something like that. This is not harmful but it will be escaped. So is this a false positive of the protection? Or there are some more sophisticated protection against XSS on server side?

Answer (score 1):

First, what [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) and similar functions do isn't removing dangerous code, it's ***encoding data as HTML***.

So, what `htmlspecialchars` does **not** do is the following:

- Receive data
- Find dangerous HTML code and replace this by harmless code
- Return the sanitized data

But it does the following:

- Receive data
- Convert this data to HTML, so that when this code is displayed it will look **the same** as when the original data would be viewed without being parsed by an HTML parser.
- Return the HTML code

➥ [You can see the difference here](http://jsbin.com/medososa/1)

Additionally, since you're asking this, you may be misunderstanding **where** XSS prevention should be applied. Encoding data as HTML shouldn't be done when it is received, but when it is outputted by the web server.

So, you should **not** be doing it like this:

- Server receives data from a client
- **Server escapes the data as HTML**
- Server processes the data
- Server outputs the data to the client

But like this:

- Server receives data from a client
- Server processes the data
- **Server escapes the data as HTML**
- Server outputs the data to the client

Comment: First of all, I don't understand the difference between two. Can you elaborate? And I wanted to say escaping all special character will incur escaping harmless input.

Comment: @Naman I've improved my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes, It helped. thanks. It means there is no protection which identify that this a harmful input, so only this should be encoded?

Comment: @Naman I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but what `htmlentities` does is taking data and generating HTML that, when parsed as HTML, will show the **same** data that `htmlentities` received. (Okay, to get it to look exactly the same you would have to style the resulting HTML with [`font-family: monospace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) and [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) or wrap it in a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag.)

Comment: +1. There is no such thing as harmful input, only input that isn't handled correctly. Trying to address XSS by filtering “bad” things at the input layer is a deeply mistaken strategy that can never fully work; the correct approach is to handle the data correctly: here, by HTML-escaping content you put into HTML; and similarly JS-escaping content you put into JS, and so on for every different kind of context. There is certainly a place for input validation, and you'll definitely want to do it for business-logic purposes, but it is not your primary defence against injection attacks.